# I am using Handlebars in my project. I want to show only the first element in an array. How can i do that?

Tags: handlebars.js

```
   <body>

<!--This is our template. -->
<!--Data will be inserted in its according place, replacing the brackets.-->
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each_when profile "gender" "female"}}
        {{from}} ({{gender}})<br> 
    {{/each_when}}
</script>

<!--Your new content will be displayed in here-->
<div class="content-placeholder"></div>

<script>
var json = {
    "profile": [
        { "gender": "female", "from": "Olivia" },
        { "gender": "female", "from": "Meagen" },
        { "gender": "female",   "from": "Aaron"  },
        { "gender": "female",   "from": "Aaron"  }
    ]
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('each_when', function(list, k, v, opts) {
    console.log(arguments);
    var i, result = '';
    for(i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
        if(list[i][k] == v)
            result = result + opts.fn(list[i]);
    return result;
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('get_length', function (obj) {
 return obj.length;
}); 


var t = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
$('body').append(t(json));
</script>
</body>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!--This is our template. -->
<!--Data will be inserted in its according place, replacing the brackets.-->
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each_when profile "gender" "female"}}
        {{from}} ({{gender}})<br> 
    {{/each_when}}
</script>

<!--Your new content will be displayed in here-->
<div class="content-placeholder"></div>

<script>
var json = {
    "profile": [
        { "gender": "female", "from": "Olivia" },
        { "gender": "female", "from": "Meagen" },
        { "gender": "female",   "from": "Aaron"  },
        { "gender": "female",   "from": "Aaron"  }
    ]
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('each_when', function(list, k, v, opts) {
    console.log(arguments);
    var i, result = '';
    for(i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
        if(list[i][k] == v)
            result = result + opts.fn(list[i]);
    return result;
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('get_length', function (obj) {
 return obj.length;
}); 


var t = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
$('body').append(t(json));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

- Olivia (female)
- Meagen (female)
- Aaron (female)
- Aaron (female)

**but I want only first one:**

- Olivia (female)

Also, I am using **{{@index}}** to show the array index, but it is not working for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: You say you are using {{@index}}, but in your code I do not see it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you want the first element in the array _after_ it is filtered for "females" or _before_?

Comment: yes i want want the first element in the array after it is filtered

Comment: Your helper won't permit you to do that because it is doing the filtering of the array at the same time that it builds the result. You will need either to modify your helper or to do the filtering _before_ passing the data to the template method. The latter is the better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your helper to:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_when', function(list, k, v, opts) {
  var match = list.findIndex(function(item) {
    return (item[k] === v);
  });
  return (match >= 0) ? opts.fn(list[match]) : '';
});
```

You want to find the first match and return the results only for that match.

Here's the full html working to show only the first match:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!--This is our template. -->
<!--Data will be inserted in its according place, replacing the brackets.-->
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each_when profile "gender" "female"}}
    {{from}} ({{gender}})<br>
    {{/each_when}}
</script>

<!--Your new content will be displayed in here-->
<div class="content-placeholder"></div>

<script>
    var json = {
        "profile": [
            { "gender": "female", "from": "Olivia" },
            { "gender": "female", "from": "Meagen" },
            { "gender": "male",   "from": "Aaron"  },
            { "gender": "male",   "from": "Aaron"  }
        ]
    };

    Handlebars.registerHelper('each_when', function(list, k, v, opts) {
        var match = list.findIndex(function(item) {
            return (item[k] === v);
        });
        return (match >= 0) ? opts.fn(list[match]) : '';
    });

    Handlebars.registerHelper('get_length', function (obj) {
        return obj.length;
    });


    var t = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
    $('body').append(t(json));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDITED TO EXTEND WITH REQUEST FROM COMMENT:

To get the first person for each unique gender, you could add another helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_unique', function(list, k, opts) {
  var foundKeys = {},
    results = '';
  list.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!foundKeys[item[k]]) {
      results = results + opts.fn(item);
      foundKeys[item[k]] = true;
    }
  });
  return results;
});
```

To use this, try out this revised sample (it has examples that show unique by `gender` and unique by `from`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <!--This is our template. -->
<!--Data will be inserted in its according place, replacing the brackets.-->
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars">
  <p>With 'each_when':</p>
  {{#each_when profile "gender" "female"}}
    {{from}} ({{gender}})<br>
  {{/each_when}}
  <hr/>
  <p>With 'each_unique' on gender:</p>
  {{#each_unique profile "gender"}}
    {{from}} ({{gender}})<br>
  {{/each_unique}}
  <hr/>
  <p>With 'each_unique' on from:</p>
  {{#each_unique profile "from"}}
  {{from}} ({{gender}})<br>
  {{/each_unique}}
</script>

<!--Your new content will be displayed in here-->
<div class="content-placeholder"></div>

  <script>
var json = {
  "profile": [
    { "gender": "female", "from": "Olivia" },
    { "gender": "female", "from": "Meagen" },
    { "gender": "male",   "from": "Aaron"  },
    { "gender": "male",   "from": "Aaron"  }
  ]
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('each_when', function(list, k, v, opts) {
  var match = list.findIndex(function(item) {
    return (item[k] === v);
  });
  return (match >= 0) ? opts.fn(list[match]) : '';
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('get_length', function (obj) {
  return obj.length;
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('each_unique', function(list, k, opts) {
  var foundKeys = {},
    results = '';
  list.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!foundKeys[item[k]]) {
      results = results + opts.fn(item);
      foundKeys[item[k]] = true;
    }
  });
  return results;
});

var t = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
$('body').append(t(json));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `each_unique` helper is a bit more complex in that we have to track if we have reported on this key value yet. We do this by providing a `foundKeys` object that will record each unique key value it finds, preventing it from including further results with the same key value on subsequent iterations through the `forEach()`.

Comment: i have one more question from same context. what if i do not filter for any of 'male' and 'female' gender. I want to show complete array and do not want repetition of array. I mean to say i just want to show first occurrence from each array. for example **Olivia (female)** and **Aaron (male)** only.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your further question. Also, I made a slight improvement on the `each_when` handler I provided previously (cleaner code).

Comment: Thanks.. and its great. U are a true programmer. I have just started learning **handlebars**. I was struggling with this problem from many days. I do not have words how to say **thank u**. U made my day. **thanks... thank u very much.**

Comment: You are doing quite well for only just starting.